# How To Enable "Touch Bar typing suggestions" on Firefox Browser?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, settings, firefox, touch-bar

**How do you have the Touch Bar show word and emoji suggestions when typing?**

## Expected

When typing text while using Firefox browser, the Touch Bar is expected to provide suggestions, i.e. words and emojis.

e.g. Chrome enables this feature

[image: Chrome Touch Bar]

## Actual

The Touch Bar does not provide word or emoji suggestions when using Firefox browser.

[image: Firefox Touch Bar]

This seems potentially related to the *Keyboard* setting *Touch Bar typing suggestions* that is not showing for Firefox.

[image: Touch Bar typing suggestions]

## Configuration

- macOS: 11.3.1
- Firefox: 88.0.1

Comment: This is likely an option that the developer builds into the app. Have you asked this on the Firefox forums? The could answer that question more definitively. I am on Catalina and the same version of FF does not show suggestions while Brave (based on Chrome) does show suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation and for verifying @SteveChambers. I've created a [forum](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/how-to-enable-touch-bar-typing-suggestions-on-macos-firefox-browser/80249) post per your suggestion.